# Appending span to corresponding li element (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, append

I am new to JS and have a problem appending a span to the correct location.  I have a checklist that has an optional text input.  When the checkbox is checked and the text input has value I want to display the text of the checkbox value and the text input value.  If text input is empty I want to just display the value of the checked box.  I have tried this:

```
    function addBreakfastCheck1(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="protein"]:checked');
      let servingTexts = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="servingTexts1"]');
      let li;
      let span;
      checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
          li = document.createElement('li');
          li.className = 'list-group-item';
          li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(checkbox.value));
          breakfastResult1.appendChild(li);
        }
      })
    
      servingTexts.forEach(function(servingText) {
        if (servingText && servingText.value) {
          span = document.createElement('span');
          span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ' + servingText.value));
          li.appendChild(span)
        }
      })
    }
```

It appends all the text input values to the last li element on submit.  How do I get each span to append to the corresponding li element?

Comment: you have no element called: breakfastResult1

Comment: I would suggest you to add the HTML part to your question and - even better - an entire sample of the code giving you troubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two loops. You should loop over all the checkboxes (not just the checked ones). `forEach()` sends the array index as another parameter, you can use that to index into the textboxes to get the corresponding value there.

```js
function addBreakfastCheck1(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="protein"]');
  let servingTexts = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="servingTexts1"]');
  checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox, i) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      li.className = 'list-group-item';
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(checkbox.value));
      let servingText = servingTexts[i];
      if (servingText && servingText.value) {
        let span = document.createElement('span');
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ' + servingText.value));
        li.appendChild(span)
      }
      breakfastResult1.appendChild(li);
    }
  })
}
```